# IS the phrase "Gentle Into That Good Night" making a reference to something else in this context?

Tags: headlinese

In this headline:

"
Gentle Into That Good Night? Not Boris Johnson.

The British prime minister may be leaving Downing Street, but few expect him to cede the spotlight, or abandon the prospect of regaining his position."

is "Gentle Into That Good Night" a reference or does it have a cultural/local meaning?

Comment: The poem by Dylan Thomas is called: Do not go gentle into that good night. It is easy to google.

Answer (score 6):

It is a reference to a well-known poem by Dylan Thomas [Do not go gentle into that good night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_not_go_gentle_into_that_good_night) in which he exhorts his elderly father not to accept death willingly.

The text is [here](https://poets.org/poem/do-not-go-gentle-good-night).